# Jquery CSS Multiple "Tiles" without having to add more Jquery code for every tile

Tags: jquery, css, microsoft-metro

My question is I want to make a metro styled Tile. I got that running but i want more than one and I don't know how to use jquery code multiple times or css code without bugging.

Here is how far i got with the `Tile`

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NE2j7/3/)

Comment: You already have a `tile` class set up, just continue to use it for new tiles.

Comment: i tried to continue but it bugs out here you can see.

 [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NE2j7/4/)

Comment: I've added a demo below. Should work as you want it to. You can modify it to absolute position the tile in the middle of the screen whit the class "open".

Comment: Check out tile that I created in js in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5mWdL/27/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it with classes instead:
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Zx3m/2/)

You can only add one of each ID, which breaks your code when you use multiple tiles.

```
$(".tile").on("click", function (e) { //opens the login
    e.stopPropagation();
    if(!$(this).hasClass('open') ) {
        $(this).animate({
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "100%"
        }, 1000).addClass('open');
    }
});
$(".close").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().stop().animate({
        "width": "100px",
        "height": "50px"
    }, 1000).removeClass('open');
});
```

Comment: I i work with this if all works as i want it i will check this answer